# did anyone summarize/organize the laws of marriage (kesubois) after the Shulchan Aruch was written

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, marriage, shalom-bayit

[i see](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F#.D7.90.D7.91.D7.9F_.D7.94.D7.A2.D7.96.D7.A8) that there is no aruch hashulchan for hilchois kesubois

is there anything similar?
someone who explains the shulchan aruch hilshos kezubois, or someone who lived after the shulchan aruch and summarizes/organizes these laws in his own way

Comment: from 178.27 in the end it seems he started writing it (is there a way i can find his incomplete manuscript) ( http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14243&st=&pgnum=770 )

Comment: Try "Is there anyone who comments on SA Hilchos Kesubos" in your header.

Comment: and also from the end of 6.30  http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14243&st=&pgnum=51

Comment: The aruch haShulchan wrote his work on ketubot too, but it's currently missing

Comment: Maybe someone someday will find a manuscript in a geniza or something. That would be awesome. Otherwise חבל על דאבדין

Comment: @Double its been a while since we discussed this, but considering the type of person the Aruch Hashulchan was, I wonder if he didn't view his Or Layisharim as his official work on this subject.

Comment: Are you asking about all the laws of marriage, or only the laws of ketubot?

Comment: @mevaqesh I am not sure what the difference is , I guess both

Comment: @DoubleAA Is it know what happened to it?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin He wrote the work in pamphlets of 30 simanim or so. So that pamphlet got lost somehow (probably the wars in europe didn't help anything). Maybe a copy will show up someday in some Geniza.

Comment: @hazoriz The kesubah is just the document that legally binds the husband (and his estate, if he dies first) to look after his wife, as well as penalizing him if he divorces her (oversimplified, but that's the gist of it). Marriage is much more complicated than that - the kesubah doesn't even do anything with regard to their getting married. It's worth noting that we have one tractate that deals with the kesubah document - Maseches Kesubos - and a separate one that deals with marriage - Maseches Kiddushin.

Answer (score 3):

it seems the [Encyclopedia Talmudit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopedia_Talmudit) did in its 4th volume under the entery baal "בעל"

There also is “Dinei Ishut” by 
Rabbi Ezra Batzri, Head of the Beit Din of Jerusalem.

Also אוצר הפוסקים (oitser haposkim)

Comment: maybe the levush

Answer (score 3):

Rabbi Dr. [Louis Epstein](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3622193) (d. 1949) authored an exemplary work in both summarizing and organizing in his valuable work 'The Marriage Contract' ([here](https://hebrewbooks.org/4156) is a link to the Hebrew ed. 'תולדות הכתובה בישראל').

Answer (score 3):

The Chief Rabbi of Bat Yam, [HaRav Eliyahu Bar Shalom](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95_%D7%91%D7%A8-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D), has an encyclopedic, nine volume masterpiece entitled [Mishpat HaKetubah](http://www.lehmanns.co.uk/mwpt-hktvbh-h-krkim.html), in which he addresses every aspect of Hilchot Ketubot.

Comment: +1 just to double check not just document

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: is this set about the Kesuba document or it also includes the laws of kesubos (obligations of each party)(which is what I  looking for)?

Comment: Ah, I see. I believe one of the volumes has the word שעבודים on the spine, meaning it's about the obligations, as well.

Comment: but it also might be only about the obligations of the husband , (which he maybe took onhimself by the kesuba) but not the obligations of the wife , (thank you for telling me about the set)